# How to get the width and height of an image by Url in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, getimagesize

I have in a Google Sheet a list of images by URL. Images are on a remote server.
I got the preview in my Sheet by the Image (URL) function.

Is there a way to get the width and height of each remote image in each row by formula or script?

[image: Example]

Answer (score -1):

Looking through the Google Community docs, found this question [asked here with no apparent solution.](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/14477363?hl=en)

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but you could use the `IMAGE` function to set the dimensions your images.

> IMAGE(url, [mode], [height], [width])
>
> url - The URL of the image, including protocol (e.g. http://).
>
> The value for url must either be enclosed in quotation marks or be a
>   reference to a cell containing the appropriate text. mode - [ OPTIONAL
>   - 1 by default ] - The sizing mode for the image
>
> 1 resizes the image to fit inside the cell, maintaining aspect ratio.
>
> 2 stretches or compresses the image to fit inside the cell, ignoring
>   aspect ratio.
>
> 3 leaves the image at original size, which may cause cropping.
>
> 4 allows the specification of a custom size.
>
> Note that no mode causes the cell to be resized to fit the image.
>
> height - [ OPTIONAL ] - The height of the image in pixels. mode must
>   be set to 4 in order to set a custom height.
>
> width - [ OPTIONAL ] - The width of the image in pixels. mode must be
>   set to 4 in order to set a custom width.